# Flutter - Not able to scroll Listview

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to write basic Listview example, however not able to scroll down, screen is fixed not able to view all items.

Tried with working example from flutter official documentation (displaying Listview till items29) https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Not able to figure out Whether it is settings issue or other.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class mySquare extends StatelessWidget {
  String child;
  mySquare({required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(height: 200, color: Colors.amber, child: Text(child)),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List posts = ['post1', 'post2', 'post3', 'post4', 'post5', 'post6'];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: posts.length,
        itemBuilder: ((BuildContext context, index) {
          return mySquare(
            child: posts[index],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: should work fine, try to  test on different device

Comment: It's not an issue, probably in the screen you using there is no need to scroll.

Comment: Thanks all for valuable time and efforts. I tried with Pixal 6 Emulator with latest OS and Pie. Just restarted my machine and working fine.

Comment: My answer was correct that is no issue with your code. Can you accept my answer, pls @user3397828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I launched your code on Android emulator and it works as **expected**.

If the device is big enough for all items `ListView` wouldn't scroll

[image]